# Proof that every element of A_5 is an involution or a product of two involutions?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

It can be verified with brute force that the alternating group on 5 elements ($A_5$) has the property that every member is either an involution or can be written as the product of two involutions.  Is there a simple proof of this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $A_5$, we have four different cycle structures: the identity $(1)$, the $3$-cycles, the $5$-cycles and products of two disjoint transpositions.

The identity is the product of an any involution with itself. Products of two disjoint transpositions are involutions.

For $3$-cycles: $(123) = (13)(12) = (13)(45)(12)(45)$.

For $5$-cycles: $(12345) = (13)(45)(12)(35)$.

Just in case it isn't obvious, the general case $(abc)$ and $(abcde)$ follows by replacing $1, 2, 3, 4$ and $5$ by $a, b, c, d$ and $e$ respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The elements of $\,A_5\,$ are of the form (using the unique decomposition (up to order) of a permutation into disjoint cycles):$$(i\,j)(k\,m)\,,\,(i\,j\,k)\,,\,(i\,j\,k\,m\,n)$$The first one above is an involution, and now we prove the other two are products of involutions:$$(i\,j\,k)=(i\,k)(i\,j)\,\,,\,\,(i\,j\,k\,m\,n)=(i\,n)(i\,m)(i\,k)(i\,j)$$

**Added** m.k. proposed in her/his comment below that every element in $\,A_5\,$ should\could be expressed as product of involution **within** $\,A_5\,$ itself. Well:$$(i\,j\,k)=\left[(j\,k)(i\,m)\right]\left[(m\,k)(i\,m)\right]$$$$(i\,j\,k\,m\,n)=(i\,m\,n)(i\,j\,k)\,,\,\text{and now apply the line above}$$

Comment: I would assume that the involutions would have to be elements of $A_5$, ie. with cycle structure $(ab)(cd)$.

Comment: That wasn't given in the OP, but I suppose some cycles and their products can be chosen to give that result...I'll think about it for a while and, if I find something relevant, I'll add an edit. Thanks @m.k.

Comment: It isn't hard: $(123)=(12)(45)\cdot (13)(45)$, and $(12345)=(12)(35)\cdot (13)(45)$.

Answer (score 2):

Two involutions generate a dihedral group, so we'd like to show that the alternating group on five symbols is a union of dihedral groups.

One conceptual way to do this is to identify the alternating group with PSL(2,4) and use the very easy subgroup structure of such groups $\operatorname{PSL}(2,p^k)$: every element is either a *p*-element (and so not a product of involutions unless $p^k \mod 4$ is 0 or 1) or a member of one of two conjugacy classes of dihedral subgroups of orders $p^k\pm 1$ (the normalizers of the split and the non split tori).

In our case $p^k=4$, so the only elements not handled by the two tori are the involutions themselves.

Comment: It might not hurt to say it more clearly: Every element of PSL(2,q)  is a product of two involutions iff q is 0 or 1 mod 4, and PSL(2,q) is a union of dihedral groups iff q is 0, 1, or 2 mod 4.